# Xcode 6.1 Yosemite Debug Area no output

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to run a working library on a different computer.  Installed Xcode6.1 and updated from Mavericks to Yosemite OS and the Debug area opens and closes quickly with no output.  No output in terminal either.  Installed the latest command line tools.  Working fine on my other machine, anyone else having this issue?

Comment: have you tried to re open the output view with the icon on the bottom bar? Maybe it just hides for some unknown reason but the view is just minimized...

Comment: Don't think so, should have also included that the Debug area is stuck on "No Selection", when I want it to be set to the command line

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate manually, view->Debug Area->Activate Console or with the icons at the right